# React native getInitialURL not nullify after use

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

After using Linking.getInitialURL() the URL stay there.

I am using react-native-router-flux to navigate.

when users log out I run

```
   import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
    NativeModules.DevSettings.reload()
```

What happens is the react-navigation do Linking.getInitialURL()
and if there any result so it navigates automatically to the page.

how to reset Linking.getInitialURL() after use ?
happens only on android

Comment: `NativeModules.DevSettings.reload()` is from developer menu, it shouldn't be used for production apps (not sure if it's even available in production).

Why do you need to reload your whole app on logout? That seems strange. Your state management should handle that. React Navigation can handle navigating automatically on logout https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Comment: You absolutely right - in prod we use RNRestart.Restart().
The app builds in a way that for simple logout we need to change the whole structure.

Answer (score -1):

React Navigation 5 provides an option to specify a custom `getInitialURL` method which you can use:

```js
<NavigationContainer
  linking={{
    // ... linking config
    getInitialURL() {
      return YourCustomModule.getInitialURL();
    },
  }}
>
  {/* content */}
</NavigationContainer>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#linkinggetinitialurl

For the implementation, since you're reloading the whole JS, the code cannot be in JS as the state is lost on reload. You'll need to write a custom native module where you can clear the initial URL when reloading.